# Can't port forward port 8080 between WSL2 and Windows host, though other ports work fine

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a Spring webserver running on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, which would run on port 8080 by default, and it is to be accessed from other devices on LAN. I did the port forwarding from port 8080 on Windows to port 8080 on WSL2 by running the following Power Shell command, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4).

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8080 connectaddress=172.18.98.54
```

, where 172.168.98.54 is my WSL2 IP address. I also allowed inbound connections on the Windows 11 Firewall to port 8080.

Even though the command ran fine, the port forwarding did not seem to work, as I could not access the website by Windows IP address from other devices on LAN. I could only access it from Windows host by using "localhost" in the URL.

Then I decided to change to webserver to run on port 8111 and did the port forwarding from 8111 Windows to 8111 WSL, and now the webserver can be accessed from other devices on LAN on port 8111.

Are there any mechanisms that block port forwarding specifically on port 8080 and other ports? Can I manage to use port forward 8080 somehow?

---

I have also run a test http server called Rebex on Windows on port 8080 and I have been able to access the website from other devices on lan by Windows IP address, so the Windows 8080 port seems to be OK.

---

EDIT:
As suggested by @NotTheDr01ds, here is a command that lists firewall rules applied to 8080. It displays the single manual rule that I created.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetFirewallPortFilter |? { "8080" -in $_.LocalPort } | Get-NetFirewallRule


Name                          : {B5E2FCB9-C589-40F6-8FDD-C07A06AEC496}
DisplayName                   : Bruno80e8080
Description                   : Permitir inbound nas portas 80 e 8080
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Any
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : A regra foi analisada com êxito no repositório. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses : {}
```

Comment: My first inclination would be to think something else was running on 8080, but things are working on `localhost`, so that shouldn't be it.  Is there a chance that there's both an `Allow` rule and a `Block` rule?  From an Admin PowerShell, does `Get-NetFirewallPortFilter |? { "8080" -in $_.LocalPort } | Get-NetFirewallRule` show anything interesting?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for the comment. The command only displayed the single manual rule that I created. I will paste the output of the command on an edit of the original post.

Comment: This one is bugging me - Every time I think I have an idea, I test it, and it doesn't seem like it fits your situation.  The firewall rules look normal, of course.  Two more troubleshooting steps --  This is a long shot, but my next troubleshooting step would be to try with something besides Spring.  `python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0` is my usual go-to for sanity checks.  I'm expecting it will have the same problem as Spring ...

Comment: Second, does `netsh interface portproxy show all` show anything out of the ordinary?